# Socket Timeout between Azure websites and Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

We have a Azure website and a Linux VM on the Azure Infrastructure.

The Websites opens a socket to the VMs. We have found that from time to time a connection is refused with the following error: ERRTIMEOUT, once this happens, all connections from the same Website affinity to the same VM are refused. Reseting the VM Application or the Reseting the Website application by scaling it up and then down solves the problem.

Suggestions and solutions are welcomed.

Comment: It seems you run out of connections, can you post some code on how you create and close your connections?

Comment: How this is possible? when this issue occurs a connection to the VM with the very same port is possible. it is also possible from other affinities on the same website. We have tried to stress test the VM via the Website and it did created ERRTIMEOUT, but after few minutes it have recovered without any problem. In the issue we that we are describing here the connection never restores.

Answer (score 2):

If the solution was re-setting the websites I would expect the problem to be exhausting ports on website. On the other hand if the problem goes away when re-setting the VM then it could be port exhaustion on that machine.

Looks like you manage to work around the issue by resetting either  one or the other.

I suspect an alternative to this would be to catch the error and implement some sort of back off. I suspect the re-setting operation is causing an interruption on the number of requests being flown out that lets the app catch up and start accepting new ones.